# What are limitations of ARM Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, arm

Is [ARM Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm) equal to X86 versions or it's limited? If so, what are limitations?

Comment: install it and check?

Comment: I'm looking to buy a board, but I don't have one at the moment to check. This is the reason I'm asking this question actually. I am looking to buy [this](http://www.hardkernel.com/renewal_2011/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G135341370451)

Comment: If you don't have the board yet, you may still be able to install GNU root on your phone (if your phone is Android). I think that is debian, but should be very similar to Ubuntu. There are also hourly ARM server providers such as pocket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of supporting several architectures is to provide "the same system" on all platforms. Programs that are not written for ARM will not run on it, that goes without saying. In general, all major services will be included, some desktop applications may not be.

Comment: To give an idea of what doesn't work, it is usually proprietary/third party things. "not all applications support ARM. You can install GIMP, LibreOffice and so on but you won't be able to install Skype or Steam for example. " -- http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-on.html